# CSRF token nuxt with Laravel

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I built a website based on Nuxt.js and Laravel and I now need to implement a contact form.

The problem is that I am not sure how to make the form secure in the sense of not anyone that is posting to my endpoint could send a message. Is there any way to incorporate the csrf token with my nuxt.js form?

The only solution I thought is having a captcha, but I thought I would ask if there is any way to avoid it? (Or having both)

Comment: how is the form being send, through ajax?

Comment: Even with CSRF anyone can send post requests (valid) they just need to acquire the token which you give away when user hits `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stop human spamming (people can pass captcha).

To prevent scripts/robots there are multiple solutions but are not perfect.

First you can limit your endpoint calls using throttle middleware on your endpoint. This will limit the number of calls for that endpoint. This might affect how many (real) users can submit the form.

Another way of protecting your api is to have a app secret and app key (see laravel passport). Even the form is public all api calls should be authorized. Means that clients should pass app keys and secret when making a request.

Using CORS can help you to allow only calls from specific domain. By default Laravel CORS package will allow all domains. You can limit that only to your client domain.

Hope it helps.